# Linux Mint doesn't write Arabic letters

Tags: fonts, character-encoding, natural-language

I installed arabic fonts for Linux mint and i can switch between arabic and English, but it seems that mint cannot write arabic letters for example renaming a file or writing in any text-editor, when typing in arabic nothing appears. Note that it can read arabic letters and i was writting and reading arabic in other distributions like ubuntu or Gnome. What is the problem?

Comment: Go to keyboard >> layouts and move Arabic to the top

Comment: Same problem, nothing appears when typing in arabic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution:

1- Go to Input method in setting

2- Install UIM and make it as an input method

3- Restart